# Initwindow and Initgraph stops program

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw, bgi, winbgi

initwindow and initgraph just stop the program. It still compiles, and it shows me the process return message afterwards and all that, but anything after it just doesn't do anything.

I have the latest versions of MinGW and Codeblocks installed, and I've done all the putting winbgim files in their places and pasted the text in the compiler settings and all that.

Code below:

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Check"<<endl;
    int page=1;
//   initwindow(1200, 768);
    int gd=DETECT,gm;
    cout<<"Check2"<<endl;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,"");
    cout<<"Check3"<<endl;

    int a=50, b=50;
    circle(a,b, 50);


    while(true){

    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT)){
        //if key pressed is right
        a=a+25;

    }
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT)){
        //if key pressed is left
        a=a-25;

    }
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)){
        //if key pressed is left
        b=b-25; //remember top left is 0, 0

    }
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)){
        //if key pressed is left
        b=b+25; //remember top left is 0, 0

    }


    setactivepage(page); //to draw
    //draw

    setvisualpage(1-page); //to show
    delay(20);
    cleardevice();
    circle(a,b, 50);
    page=1-page;
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***I have the latest versions of MinGW and Codeblocks installed,*** That could be the problem. The binaries you are using could likely be incompatible with your compiler. You may need to use a really old compiler or find updated binaries.

Comment: Got any ideas of where i can find those old versions?

Comment: If you did download the winbgi from 2004 / 2005 you should be able to install a MinGW 4 from here: [https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/OldFiles/](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/OldFiles/)

Comment: I believe there is also a newer version of winbgi that you can search. I don't have a link however.